# SQL Server 2005 - how can I select a specific part of a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the string **&string=45646874&v1=67&v2=test** and from that I would like to grab the string **45646874** and sometime this extraction will have **8** characters sometimes **7** sometimes **5** etc.

So I need to search in **&string=45646874&v1=67&v2=test** and grab everything that comes after **string=** and before the next **&**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not have any built in regex extraction support, but we can handle this using the base string functions as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '&string=45646874&v1=67&v2=test' AS col UNION ALL
    SELECT 'blah blah &string=ABCDEF123&v1=hello&v2=goodbye'
)

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('&string=', col) + 8,
              CHARINDEX('&', col, CHARINDEX('&string=', col) + 1) -
              CHARINDEX('&string=', col) - 8) AS output
FROM cte;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Hey Tim, I have to do it in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, that has some limitations, https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/sql_reference/

Comment: Considerations
The SQL support for the Query Activity is based on SQL Server 2005 capabilities.

Only SELECT statements to data extension or data views in an account or in the parent account
Nested Queries
UNION
JOIN
GROUP BY
Conditional Statements
IF Constructs
CASE Statements
Functions
Most functions (i.e. MIN, MAX) are supported
CAST and CONVERT
Unsupported elements
Variables
Cursors
User Defined Functions
Transaction and Locking
GOTO
PRINT
Any sp_* stored procedure
EXEC
Temporary Tables and Common Table Expressions
TEXT and IMAGE Functions

Comment: On SQL Server 2005, without `CHARINDEX` support, I'm not sure there is a solution unless we make assumptions about the query string.  Does `&v1` always follows the `&string` parameter?

Comment: we can use charindex, and sometimes we will have `&string=45646874&v1=67&v2=tes`, or `&string=45646874&v2=tes&v1=67`, or `&string=45646874&v8=tes&v1=67`, but we will always have the `string=`  `some numbers` and `&`

Comment: @FelipeJordani If you can use `CHARINDEX` then my answer should work for you, regardless of where the query parameters appear.  Disregard the `UNION ALL` you see in the CTE above.  This is only there for testing purposes, so that you can cut and paste my answer directly into SQL Server.

Comment: I grab this part of the code `SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('&string=', col) + 8,
              CHARINDEX('&', col, CHARINDEX('&string=', col) + 1) -
              CHARINDEX('&string=', col) - 8) AS output` and my server is retrieving `failed due to system error`

Comment: Yeah...so as I was saying `CHARINDEX` is not available on 2005.  In order to give an answer using `PATINDEX` (which _is_ available on 2005) we would have to make big assumptions about the query string, and you may not be satisfied with those assumptions.

Comment: I used charindex in another easier case `substring(LinkContent,CHARINDEX('aCategoryRange=',LinkContent)+15,1) as category_id` and works

Comment: Lightbulb: Does every one of your query strings have two `&` ?  Maybe my query is failing due to the data.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I add a where clause to only grab the row on my database that has more than 1 `&` and now works

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
DECLARE @String varchar(100)= '&string=45646874&v1=67&v2=test'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,(CHARINDEX('string=',@string)+7),(CHARINDEX('&',@string,2)-(CHARINDEX('string=',@string)+7)))
```